# pytz failed to import in background runnable script in Windmill

Tags: python, runnable, pypi, pytz, windmill

I coded my inline script and successfully imported pytz module,
but when i type the same line
[image]

```
import pytz
```

it failed, error said: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
i try both

```
#extra_requirements:
#pytz==2024.1
```

and

```
#requirements:
#pytz==2024.1
```

they don't help at all.
I tried to import snowflake connector in my background script also failed

my assumption was that background runnable script won't support those module which required to be downloaded. Or is there any other way that I can import pytz in my python background runnable scripts?

Comment: no screenshot please. copy them as code. screenshots are not indexed by search engines. there is nothing wrong with adding screenshots but you should look to make it searchable , that increases your chances of it being answered.